# Density in reflexive spaces

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, reference-request

I'd like to see a proof to the following result related to density in reflexive spaces

> Let $V_1 \subset V_2$ hilbert spaces. If $ v \in V_2$ is such that
>   \begin{equation}
> 0=\langle v,w \rangle \quad \forall w \in V_1 \Rightarrow v = 0,
> \end{equation}
>   then 
>   $V_1$ is dense in $V_2.$

Comment: Funny question, because, if $V_1$ is a vector subspace of $V_2$ and $V_2$ is a Hilbert (resp. Banach) space, then $V_1$ is a Hilbert (resp. Banach) space if and only if $V_1$ is closed. And the only closed *dense* subset of $V_2$ is $V_2$ itself.

Comment: I suspect the situation is that $V_1$ is not a Hilbert space in the subspace topology, but rather that the topology on $V_1$ is strictly finer than the topology induced by $V_2$, like for the inclusion of Sobolev spaces, $H^2 \subset H^1 \subset L^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $0=\langle v,w\rangle$ for all $w\in V_1$ implies $v=0$.
This is equivalent to say that the orthogonal complement of $V_1$ in $V_2$ is just zero, $V_1^\perp=\{0\}$. This in turn implies that $V_1$ is dense in $V_2$.